# Kernel of Differential Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have a linear differential equation:
$$\left[D^{n}+a_{1}D^{n-1}+\dots+a_{n}D^{0}\right]y(t)=0$$
Where $y$ is an analytic function.

How can we prove that the kernel of the differential operator
$$\left[D^{n}+a_{1}D^{n-1}+\dots+a_{n}D^{0}\right]$$
has dimension $n$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is domain space of your operator!

Comment: polynomail or C^{1} or .....?

Comment: Anything will do for my purpose. Say analytic.

Comment: This $n$-degree operator polynomial $\left[D^{n}+a_{1}D^{n-1}+\dots+a_{n}D^{0}\right]$ has dimension $n$ can be proved by fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We call the expression $$a_nD^n+a_{n-1}D^{n-1}+...+a_2D^2+a_1D+a_0~~~(*)$$ a linear $n$th-order differential operator. Since $(*)$ is a polynomial in symbol $D$, somone can denote it as $P(D)$. It seems you know that when all $a_i$ are constant, $P(D)$ can be factored into differential operators of lower order, so that makes us to treat $P(D)$ as an ordinary polynomial.However, these extracted factors can commute with each other. Now remind The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra about $P(D)$. For example, if $$(D^2+5D+6)y=0$$ then $$(D+3)(D+2)y=0$$ Or when $$[D^2-2\alpha D+(\alpha^2+\beta^2)]^n$$ annihilate $y(x)$, then $y(x)$ contains a linear combination of the following independent functions: $$\{\text{e}^{\alpha x}\cos(\beta x),x\text{e}^{\alpha x}\cos(\beta x),...x^{n-1}\text{e}^{\alpha x}\cos(\beta x),\text{e}^{\alpha x}\sin(\beta x),x\text{e}^{\alpha x}\sin(\beta x),...x^{n-1}\text{e}^{\alpha x}\sin(\beta x)\}$$

Comment: I missed you today :-(  I lost internet access for a few hours ago (well, 8 hours ago, for a couple hours!), when you were "around".

Comment: @amWhy: Honestly, I have had such that problem in my tel line. In fact there are some inconsistency with web. Now, I am in the university. And for next hours, I don't know, if the problems are implemented. :-(

Comment: Sorry to hear that, dear friend. I just experienced a span of a few hours without access (I have DSL/Broadband, so I don't have the problems I did when I had only a "dial-up" connection, but occasionally, causes me grief. But all in all, I'm grateful for the fact that interruptions are rare now. I know how frustrating it can be when "uncertainty" looms in the air, and/or when one's connection is non-dependable.